# Spherical Rectangle with TikZ / PGF Plots

Tags: pgfplots

How would you do a spherical rectangle? I know that for a sphere you do this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis equal,
colormap name=whitered,
height=20cm,
width=20cm,
view={340}{25},
axis lines = center,
ticks = none,
scale uniformly strategy=units only,
enlargelimits=0.3,
samples=20,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel={$z$},
yticklabels={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
zticklabels={,,},
]

\addplot3[
surf,
shader=flat,
opacity=0.2,
fill opacity = 0.3,
samples=50, samples y=30,
domain=-1:1,y domain=0:2*pi,
z buffer=sort,
]
({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
 {sqrt(1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
  x);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but now I want to cut it at the edges of a rectangle like this
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?  [image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis equal,
%colormap name=whitered,
height=20cm,
width=20cm,
view={340}{25},
axis lines = none,
ticks = none,
scale uniformly strategy=units only,
enlargelimits=0.3,
samples=20,
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel={$z$},
yticklabels={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
zticklabels={,,},
]

\addplot3[
surf,
shader=flat,
opacity=0.2,
fill opacity = 0.3,
samples=50, samples y=30,
domain=-0.5:0.5,y domain=-0.3:0.3,
z buffer=sort,
]
%({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
% {sqrt(1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
%  x);
(x,y,{sqrt(1-x^2-y^2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how did that work for you? I get an error:`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@onefilewithoptions #1[#2][#3]#4->\@pushfilename 
\xdef \@currname {#1}\glob...`

Comment: somehow there were added backslashes in the code before the [ and ].  No idea how they added up there; they're not in the code I copied.

Comment: I just copied it again.